# Double loop with multiple "if" conditionals

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, conditional-statements

I have two arrays with "a" which corresponds to "coordinates" in my problem and b corresponds to specific values of coordinates.
I m trying to know the lines of "a" where i got all the 3 values that is in "b" as example i would like to print the line of [2,4,6] as i have them in "b"
but nothing appears...there is a mistake...

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[2.,4.,6.]])

b = np.array([2,4,6,8,10])

for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,b.shape[0]):
        if (b[j]==a[i,0] and b[j]==a[i,1]):
            print i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    if (a[i,0] in b and a[i,1] in b and a[i,2] in b):
        print a[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `numpy` this here should also work

```
import numpy as np

a[np.all(np.in1d(a,b).reshape(a.shape),axis=1)]
```